# first variation of function defined by an integral

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Let $f$ be a function defined by $f(x) = \int_0^x \sin \phi(t) dt$. What is the first variation $\delta f(x)$ and how it is calculated?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the matter? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a wikipedia page [First variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation) with the definition and worked-out example.

In your example, instead of a  functional (which would take values in $\mathbb R$) we have a nonlinear operator, which takes values in some function space. But the calculation is  the same: 
$$ \sin(\phi(t)+\epsilon h(t)) - \sin (\phi(t))  = \epsilon \cos(\phi(t))\,h(t)+O(\epsilon^2)$$  where $O(\epsilon^2)$ is uniform in $t$ provided that $h$ is bounded on $[0,x]$. Hence, 
$$\delta f(x) = \int_0^x \cos(\phi(t))\,h(t)\,dt $$

Comment: What are these functions h() and O(), and the parameter ϵ?